# What are Fail2ban duration accepted notations?

Tags: time, fail2ban

I've been searching around for the accepted duration formats for Fail2ban Jail configuration file (maybe it is not exclusive to F2B).

I want to make sure which suffixes are valid when expressing an amount of time.

F2B configuation is not explicit regarding this: https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8#Jails

So far, it seems that following notations are accepted : m, h, d

Can anyone point me the a complete list of such suffixes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time abbreviations are accepted in fail2ban >= 0.10.
And the list of possible notations can be found in man for jail.conf, in section [TIME ABBREVIATION FORMAT](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/fail2ban/jail.conf.5.en.html#TIME_ABBREVIATION_FORMAT)

> ```
> years?, yea?, yy?
> months?, mon?
> weeks?, wee?, ww?
> days?, da, dd?
> hours?, hou?, hh?
> minutes?, min?, mm?
> seconds?, sec?, ss?
> ```

The question mark (?) means the optional character, so `day` as well as `days` (or `mo` and `mon`) can be used.